# Find the number of trailing zeros of $ 100! - 101! + ... - 109! + 110!$

Tags: divisibility, factorial, factoring

My try : I know number of trailing zeros of individual factorials, owing to their numbers of factors divisible by $5, 25$.

```
 100! till 104! : 24 zeros
 105! till 109! : 25 zeros
 110! : 26 zeros
```

So minimum number of trailing zeros will be $24$. But when subtracting, the number of trailing can increase. Without doing too many addition and multiplications, how to easily find this out?

Comment: I'm not sure how easily it is, but I'd try factoring out 100! from the expression, possibly neglecting the terms from 105! onward.

Comment: The number of trailing zeros in base 10 of $n!$ is $\sum_{i=1}^k \lfloor{\frac n {5^i}}\rfloor$

Comment: @hardmath good idea, in fact factoring $n!$ gives $f(n)=a_0+a_1n+\cdots+a_{10}n^{10}$ but since $n=100$ has two zeros (so does $a_1n$ and other terms), we are mainly interested in $a_0$ ending $=3301820$ thus $f(n)=\cdots 20$ and we get $25$ zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Try by this method

$100 ! - 101 ! + 102 ! - \ldots -109 ! + 110!$ 
= $100 ! - 101 ! (1 - 102) - 103 ! ( 1 - 104) - \ldots - 109 ! ( 1 - 110)$
=$100 ! + 101(101 !) + 103(103 !) + 105(105 !) + 107(107 !) + 109(109 !)$

Comment: How does this help? The next step is the same factoring?

Comment: Be wary of posting an attempt ("try by this method") without an actual answer to the problem posed in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo $100(100!)$, it is $100!(0!-1!+2!-3!\ldots +10!)$ and the factor is a multiple of $10$ but not $100$